# Download Documents from Sugarcrm

Tags: php, soap, sugarcrm

i am using SOAP API for `SugarCRM`. 
I want to download document   using PHP. 
I have no idea how to download the document. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are generally two "types" of documents in sugarcrm. Those added to the Document module and those added to the History sub panel in e.g. the Account module.

To retrieve documents linked to accounts you should look in the `notes` table. This also contains everything else from the history sub panel which are linked to the account, e.g. emails. You can properly filter on the document_type column, if all documents are using the same document_type. (Replace `[account_id]` and `[session_id]`)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sug="http://www.sugarcrm.com/sugarcrm" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sug:get_entry_list soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <session xsi:type="xsd:string">[session_id]/session>
         <module_name xsi:type="xsd:string">Notes</module_name>
         <query xsi:type="xsd:string">parent_type = 'Accounts' AND parent_id = '[account_id]'</query>
         <order_by xsi:type="xsd:string"></order_by>
         <offset xsi:type="xsd:int">0</offset>
         <select_fields xsi:type="sug:select_fields" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]">
           <select_fields xsi:type="xsd:string">id</select_fields>
       <select_fields xsi:type="xsd:string">name</select_fields>
           <select_fields xsi:type="xsd:string">filename</select_fields>
           <select_fields xsi:type="xsd:string">document_revision_id</select_fields>
         </select_fields>
         <max_results xsi:type="xsd:int">100</max_results>
         <deleted xsi:type="xsd:int">0</deleted>
      </sug:get_entry_list>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

To get documents from the Documents module, you basically do the same, but it takes two steps. First retrieve the documents from the `documents` table and afterwards use the `document_revision_id` to retrieve the document `id` and `filename` from the `document_revisions` table.

In order to download/retrieve a document, you need the `id` and the `filename`. Files are usually stored in `/cache/upload` in you sugarcrm root folder and are named with the `id`.
So if a document has `id=a06bfc2e-c6e9-ac53-9e7b-4bf4e4d862ca`, the document can be retrieved from `http://my-suger/cache/upload/a06bfc2e-c6e9-ac53-9e7b-4bf4e4d862ca`. The retrieved file should than be renamed to the `filename`, which you get from the web service response.

Comment: i got error like this 
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /
as i give 777 permission too

Comment: Make sure both the `upload`, `cache`, and the actual file is readable by the webserver. Moreover, you can't access `http://my-suger/cache/upload/` on a default SugarCRM installation, since the folders does not show directory listings, so you need to access the files directly.

Comment: i am checking  www.mysite.com/cache/upload/7c960758-8109-3eb2-980f-4f06958df672 wiht 777 permissions to all folders as well as file still got forbidden error.

Comment: Most likely the web server is restricting access to the folder. Check you .htaccess file in the sugar root. It might have an entry like `RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+cache/+upload`. Try to disable this. However, making the files publically available is a security concern, if you have classified information in the files. A more correct approch would be to read the files using another solution.

Comment: @kare :Acc to me it doesn't work on Firefox as it downloads direclty and you dn't know file extension in this case .  Can you please tell me what another method to use for this.

Comment: Since Amandeep is using the web service interface to retrieve documents, I reckoned that he was developing some kind of program to retrieve the documents and in that same action renaming the files. In my view it should _NOT_ be possible to directly view the documents in the upload folder with a browser (hence the default setting in the config files), since it defeats the SugarCRM security.